# Web Scraping Header issue

Tags: python, curl, beautifulsoup

I am playing about with scraping data from websites as an educational exercise. I am using python and beautiful soup.

I am basically looking at products on a page e.g. 
`http://www.asos.com/Women/Dresses/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=8799#parentID=-1&pge=0&pgeSize=5&sort=-1`

I noticed it had the parameters pge and pgeSize which I can change in the browser and give the results I would expect, but when running user python requests, it always returns the same 36 products (36 being the default)

I thought this was a header issue so I tried using curl Chrome developer tools to try and work out which headers I needed but with curl I can't get past the following response:

```
curl -c ~/cookie -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36" -X GET 'http://www.asos.com/Women/Dresses/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=8799#parentID=-1&pge=0&pgeSize=5&sort=-1'
```

Object moved

### Object moved to [here](/Women/Dresses/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=8799&r=2).

How or what is the correct way to debug and try to work this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default dresses are always returned for URL `/Women/Dresses/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=8799&r=2`.

Notice `parentID=-1&pge=7&pgeSize=5&sort=-1` are after `#` sign.

There is an additional query that fetches the right dresses and replaces them for you.

Comment: ah I see what you mean. Thanks ill try that now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an `asos` cookie, e.g. using this curl flag:

```
curl --cookie "asos=currencyid=19" 'http://www.asos.com/Women/Dresses/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=8799#parentID=-1&pge=0&pgeSize=5&sort=-1'
```

Comment: Great thanks that returns a result, but i'm now back at the same issue I had with python. It's ignoring the pge=0&pgeSize=5 and always returning 36 elements. The strange thing being I can change this in the browser and see the results on the screen but if I choose 'view source' in the code there is still 36 elements.

Comment: most probably because they use client side Javascript code to change the view to selected items; that's not possible in PHP (or at least not without Javascript interpretation)